# Prove that there exists $a,b\in S$ such that $1<a<b$ and $a\mid b.$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p>5$ be prime and

$$S=\{p-n^2\mid n\in ℕ,n^2<p\}.$$

Prove that there exists $a,b\in S$ such that
$1<a<b$ and $a\mid b.$

Here’s my try

Note that $|S|=\lfloor\sqrt p\rfloor$
and I’m trying to use pigeon hole, but I'm stuck.Can we prove this by using sum of two squares theorem?

Comment: Problems from textbooks are better suited to Math StackExchange. Please only post research level questions on MathOverflow. The tag "mathematics-education" is also not appropriate, as your question has nothing to do with mathematics pedagogy.

Comment: Note that $S$ contains $\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor$ integers and since $p>5$, $\lfloor\sqrt{p}\rfloor \geq 2$; thus, by the Pigeonhole Principle, there must exist $a,b \in S$ with $a>b$ and $a \mid b$.

Answer (score 2):

Since $p$ is prime, if we choose $m$ as large as possible with $m^2<p$ then $0 < p-m^2 < 2m$. So if we let $n=|p-m^2-m|$ then $0<n<m$. We have $p-m^2=m\pm n$, so $(p-m^2)|(m-n)(m+n)=m^2-n^2$. Adding $p-m^2$, we get $(p-m^2)|(p-n^2)$. The only problem with this is that $p$ may be one more than a square, in which case $p-m^2=1$. If this is the case then $m$ is even, so $2m=(p-(m-1)^2)|(p-1^2)=m^2$. Since $p>5$, $m>2$.

Comment: I'm not really sure this was a research level question, but only because there was a simple solution. Where did the problem come from? What was your motivation for asking it?

Comment: I don't know where it originally came from, but I do know that this is problem A38 of Problems in Elementary Number Theory (PEN), a book that consists of hundreds of olympiad-level number theoretical math problems. See https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/q1h150406p849268 for a topic on this problem.

Comment: I do hope I'm not doing the OP's homework for her/him/them. A comment from the OP at this point would be appreciated.